# Power absorbed by diode in simulation

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, current, resistors

[image]

[image]

This is a simulation in LTspice.  The graph below shows the power vs time for diode D2.

Is it a concern that in the first few microseconds, the power absorbed by diode is 500W? Is that a lot and will it cause too much heat? From my view, since it only last for such a small amount of time, you can neglect it.

Answer (score 2):

Your simulation doesn't represent reality.

The voltage source in LTspice can deliver infinite current.  Your simulation is probably pushing hundreds of amperes through the diode.

A real power supply can't do that - and if your power supply can really supply hundreds of amperes then you wouldn't be using the 1N5818 since it is only rated for 1A.

Comment: Hi, if you look at my circuit, from your experience, does it work in real life? I am planning to get that 20V AC source from a transformer connected to the plug of my house

Comment: It depends on how big your transformer is (how much current it can deliver.)  If you've got an AC arc welder transformer rated for 300A, then no it won't work.  If you have a smaller transformer rated for, say, 30A, then maybe.  If you have a small transformer rated for 500mA, then absolutely no problem.

Comment: What's wrong with big transformer? I thought all transformer will deliver the same amount of power depending on what the load requires. So, it does not matter the size?

Comment: When the capacitor is fully discharged, it will "look like" a short circuit to the transformer.  The charging capacitor can draw a very large current - just like in your simulation.  A typical small transformer can't deliver high current, so no problem.  If you have a large, empty capacitor and a transformer that can deliver ridiculously high currents, then the capacitor or the diodes could go "bang."

Comment: Oh , i did not know that A typical small transformer can't deliver high current ? Why it cant deliver high current, is it because of coil size ?

Comment: It's the size of the coil, the diameter of the wire, and the volume of the core material.

Comment: If a small transformer could deliver high current, then nobody would use big transformers.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a problem, but in the real world there are inherent resistances that will limit the current and your simulation does not include these.

The ac voltage source will have some series resistance that limits the current available from it, and the wiring will also have non-zero resistance. If you really want to know what happens to the diodes you need to include those resistances.

If you can't completely model the actual real world circuit, then you may want to consider adding **inrush current limiting**.

Comment: Hi, if you look at my circuit, from your experience, does it work in real life? I am planning to get that 20V AC source from a transformer connected to the plug of my house

Comment: In real life it works sometimes and it fails sometimes. Who knows how much current your transformer can provide or how much resistance there is in the wiring? If you always turn it on when the ac voltage is near zero then you might get lucky.